# What would be the best way to map this scenario in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a table that contains keywords. I have several other tables that can have multiple keywords (pulled from the keywords table). Here is what I have, which works, but it feels like there is a better way to map this. I'm just not sure what it would be (if anything)

```
public class Keyword
{
    public virtual int Id {get; protected set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}

public class KeywordMap : ClassMap<Keyword>
{
    public KeywordMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Not.Nullable().GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable.Length(100);
    }
}

public class Article
{
    public virtual int Id {get; protected set;}
    //... other properties omitted
    public virtual IList<Keyword> Keywords {get; set;}
}

public class ArticleMap : ClassMap<Article>
{
    public ArticleMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Not.Nullable().GeneratedBy.Identity();
        HasMany(x => x.Keywords).Inverse().Cascade.Delete();
    }
}

public class Picture
{
    public virtual int Id {get; protected set;}
    //... other properties omitted
    public virtual IList<Keyword> Keywords {get; set;}
}

public class PictureMap : ClassMap<Picture>
{
    public PictureMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Not.Nullable().GeneratedBy.Identity();
        HasMany(x => x.Keywords).Inverse().Cascade.Delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet I am not sure what you'd like to achieve... It seems like there is a table '[Keywords]', which has two columns 'Picture_Id' and 'Article_Id'.

So either it is used for a `Picture` or for `Article` (other reference is null). It could also mean, that there are multiple same values in the column 'Name'... If I do read it correctly

I guess that more suitable would be `many-to-many` relation in this case. Single set of unique `Keyword.Name`. Then there would be pairing table for each relation `[ArticleKeyword]` `[PictureKeyword]`

If this is the case, we can do map it like this (see [Fluent NHibernate HasManyToMany() Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321519/1679310) or [Fluent NHibernate - HasManyToMany...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8835864/1679310))

```
public ArticleMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).Not.Nullable().GeneratedBy.Identity();
    HasManyToMany<Keyword>(x => x.Keyword)
      .Table("ArticleKeyword")
      .ParentKeyColumn("Article_Id") // lot of mapping could be omited 
      .ChildKeyColumn("Keyword_Id")  // thanks to conventions 
      ;
```

More reading about many-to-many

- http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional
- http://ayende.com/blog/4043/nhibernate-mapping-list

Comment: "So either it is used for a Picture or for Article (other reference is null). It could also mean, that there are multiple same values in the column 'Name'... If I do read it correctly" That is correct, but there are actually 5 tables that can (optionally) have a keyword, so mapping it the way I have it, I end up with 4 null columns for each record, which seems inefficient to me.