# fluent nhibernate sqlstring produces question mark for the key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a many to many in sql and I'm trying to map it using nhibernate.
I'm getting close now after struggles to get this far but my sql string that nhibernate creates has a question mark in it, shown below.  Am I missing something?

do I need to create an add method in each class to add the other entity onto it?

Thanks,

**My problem - sql string produced by fluent nhibernate**

```
... y=productcat1_.itm_Key WHERE productcat0_.itr_Key=?
```

**object A**

```
public class Range : IEntity
{
    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**object B**

```
public class Item : IEntity
{
    public virtual IList<Range> Ranges { get; set; } 
}
```

**Mappings**

```
// Item mapping
mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Ranges)
            .Table("itr_RangeItemsAssoc")
            .ParentKeyColumn("itm_Key")
            .ChildKeyColumn("itr_ItemsKey")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate().LazyLoad();

// Range mapping
mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Items)
            .Table("itr_RangeItemsAssoc")
            .ParentKeyColumn("itr_Key")
            .ChildKeyColumn("itr_ItemRangeKey")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate().LazyLoad();
```

**Update**

Have added the following method onto my entities although I don't call them anywhere..?

```
public class Range : IEntity
{
    ....

    public virtual void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        item.Ranges.Add(this);
        Items.Add(item);
    }
}

public class Item : IEntity
{
    ...

    public virtual void AddRange(Range range)
    {
        range.Items.Add(this);
        Ranges.Add(range);
    }
}
```

**Update 2 - mapping corrections**

```
mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Ranges)
            .Table("itr_RangeItemsAssoc")  // name of the look up table
            .ParentKeyColumn("itr_ItemsKey")  // key for item in the lookup table
            .ChildKeyColumn("itm_Key")  // key column in the item table
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate().LazyLoad().Inverse();
    }


mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Items)
            .Table("itr_RangeItemsAssoc")  // name of the look up table
            .ParentKeyColumn("itr_ItemRangeKey")  // key for the range in the lookup tablei
            .ChildKeyColumn("itr_Key")  // key column in the range table
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate().LazyLoad();
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to be mentioned.

Firstly, Many-to-many is represented by pairing table, with two columns. These are playing role parent-child and child-parent.

Secondly, one end must be marked as inverse. Below the Items are marked `.Inverse()`

There is an example of the `Item` mapping

```
public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public LibraryMap()
    {
         // table, id, other properties
         ...
         HasManyToMany(x => x.Ranges)
            .Table("itr_RangeItemsAssoc")
            .ParentKeyColumn("itr_ItemRangeKey") // not itm_Key
            .ChildKeyColumn("itr_ItemsKey")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .LazyLoad();
```

The similar for a `Range`

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Items)
    .Table("itr_RangeItemsAssoc")
    .ParentKeyColumn("itr_ItemsKey") // not itr_Key
    .ChildKeyColumn("itr_ItemRangeKey")
    .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
    .LazyLoad()
    // here, the inverse
    .Inverse() // one end must be marked as inverse
    ;
```

Here you can get some idea about the mapping behind: [6.8. Bidirectional Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional)

The example of the fluent mapping many-to-many could be found here: [Mapping-by-Code - OneToMany and other collection-based relation types](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-onetomany-and-other.html) *(the second half of the article)*

Comment: are you saying that the ParentKeyColumn should be the name of the columns in the 'look up' table?  Thanks

Comment: Please, Try to check my link, to get the understanding about NHibernate. Fluent is just a way how to achieve the same (xml mapping) with fluent syntax. **And yes**. Parent means the key column, child is the other side key. And vice versa

Comment: it looks like im missing the add methods on each class?  Does that sound correct?

Comment: No. It cold be, but does not have to. Just map: HasManyToMany for both. And then, you have to be sure in code, that both sides of the relation are assigned in code, somewhere. If this would be method Add()... better. But it could be any place. just `range.Items.Add(item); item.Ranges.Add(range);` This is a good practice which should be followed...

Comment: looking into the exception I'm getting this reason: Invalid object name 'itr_RangeItemsAssoc'.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more precise mapping. This should not throw any exception, in case that the table `itr_RangeItemsAssoc` exists. I've also found an example of the mapping discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835658/

Comment: James, you've added two methods, as you say in the question uppate, but do not call them anywhere? The point is, that the assignment item-range must be done. If you place this methods on the Entities, then call them. Simply, the relation (as I noted in a comment above) must be set. Does it make sense?

Comment: Not sure where I call the add mehods?

Comment: the code doesn't crash, but inside when looking at my collection of items I get the following still: Invalid object name 'itr_RangeItemsAssoc'

Comment: The **Invalid object name 'itr_RangeItemsAssoc'** would be related to some problems with the DB table name. **Is the `itr_RangeItemsAssoc`** real name of the **pairing table?** Is not there any typo? Is not the Schema missing? e.g. [mySchema].[myTable]? Check this... the rest should work immediately